# How to view PDFs with pdf.js in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms, webview

I'm using Xamarin Forms' WebView control to show a PDF, the problem is that this control only renders it for iOS correctly, for Android this does not happen, so I must implement different solutions for each of the platforms, so I'm using the following implementation with pdf.js [recipes](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/xamarin-forms/Controls/display-pdf?fbclid=IwAR35oOt4ySm64begNPAlBTmPEUf-jnERqzHu8_ZDUdrdE_dyG9eqbYgUI2E)

My app displays PDFs that are locally in the device, but it is not showing in the customized control, the first question I have is ... Can I pass the file path to the WebView so that I can visualize it? in the following way ...

[image: path]

the previous thing to bindar the property PDF to the customized control of the following form

```
  <local:CustomWebView Uri="{Binding PDF}"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

It is worth mentioning that introducing a PDF in the content folder of the Android project in the following way

[image: Content]

and then batch it in the following way in my XAML view, it works !!!

```
   <local:CustomWebView Uri="CV.pdf"
                             HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                             VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" />
```

The way to pass the path to my PDF property from my ViewModel is the following ...

ViewModel.CS:

```
  #region Constructor
        public VisorArchivosViewModel(Evidencia evidencia)
        {
            navigationService = new NavigationService();

            this.evidencia = evidencia;

            if (evidencia != null)
            {
                PDF = evidencia.Path;

            }

        }
        #endregion
```

I know that my question is basic, but how can I show a PDF that is stored locally on my device in a WebView?

ANY HELP FOR ME¿?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize your custom renderer, to provide the local path of the PDF.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomWebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRenderer))]

{
    public class CustomWebViewRenderer : WebViewRenderer
    {
        public CustomWebViewRenderer(Context context) : base(context) { }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                if (File.Exists(customWebView.Uri))
                {
                    Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                    var finalStr = string.Format(
                            "file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}",
                            string.Format(
                                "file:///{0}",
                                WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri)
                            )
                        );
                    Control.LoadUrl(finalStr);
                }
            }
        }

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == "Uri")
            {
                var customWebView = Element as CustomWebView;
                if (File.Exists(customWebView.Uri))
                {
                    Control.Settings.AllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs = true;
                    var finalStr = string.Format(
                            "file:///android_asset/pdfjs/web/viewer.html?file={0}",
                            string.Format(
                                "file:///{0}",
                                WebUtility.UrlEncode(customWebView.Uri)
                            )
                        );
                    Control.LoadUrl(finalStr);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```